# Excel Search Date formats

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Excels 2013 mid and search function to get the date from a comment column but I don't know how to do this to cover the 8 date formats(dd/mm/yyyy, dd/mm/yy and so on). Three of my formulas are below although I would need to join them all together to capture all the date formats.The comment column can be any text with a date anywhere within it.

```
=MID(A6, SEARCH("??/??/????", A6, 1), 10)
=MID(A7, SEARCH("?/??/????", A7, 1), 9)
=MID(A8, SEARCH("??/?/????", A8, 1), 9)
```

There must be a better way of doing this as the only way I can think of is to put each formula on a separate column and then use an if statement to show the date.
Any help would be much appreciative. thanks

Sample Column data

```
Paid on 01/01/2017
Paid on 1/01/2017, Reference AAA123
Reference BBB456 Paid on  01/1/2017
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of what your A column looks like?

Comment: Can there be other numbers in the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This array formula works if there are no other numbers before the date in the string:

```
=INDEX(--TRIM(CLEAN(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),",",""),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))),MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(--TRIM(CLEAN(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),",",""),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)))),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

It parses the string by the space and iterates through each "word" till it finds the first that can be converted to a number, which a date is.

This will require that the output be formatted into the date format desired.

[image]

Comment: Just checked and this formula doesn't work if the string ends with a date, at least not in Excel 2010. Still, enough for a +1.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 my bad forgot the pesky `+1`  The edit should work now.

Comment: Thank you for this, it almost works although it doesn't like the full stops and commas, is it possible to add a substitute on a comma/Full stop to this so that it covers my second example shown on my updated sample column?

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner This worked really well, also learned a few extra functions that I was unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Regular Expressions are used for.

Here's a function that implements Regular Expressions as referenced here:  [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

(Note that you have to add the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" reference, as mentioned in the link)

```
Function showDate(thisVal As String)

    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp

    strPattern = "[0-9]?[0-9]/[0-9]?[0-9]/[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9][0-9]"

    If strPattern <> "" Then

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        Set objMatches = regEx.Execute(thisVal)
        For Each Match In objMatches             'The variable match will contain the full match
            showDate = Match
        Next

    End If

End Function
```

Use it like: `=showDate(A1)`

the bit of code:

```
    strPattern = "[0-9]?[0-9]/[0-9]?[0-9]/[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9][0-9]"
```

Controls what patterns will be looked for.  The `?` after each `[0-9]` range denotes an "optional" character, so the leading zero or one in the month can be accepted if present, but the lack of it won't cause the match/find to miss.

Do note that this solution provides the last instance of a date from a string.  If you only have one instance of a date it's fine but multiple dates per string is a consideration you have to scope for.